# Детект нативного Android 5.1 email клиента?

Tags: html, вёрстка-email

**Суть вопроса:**

Есть ли такое же условие, как представлено ниже, но для нативного `email` клиента под `Android 5.1`? Найти эту информацию не сумел.

```
<!--[if mso]>
  some code goes here...
<![endif]-->`
```